# Cant cd into folder during heroku deployment

Tags: heroku

I am trying to deploy my MERN stack to Heroku but there is an error when I try 'git push heroku master' saying 'sh: 1: cd: can't cd to ../react-front'.
My Folder 'app' has two folders: 'node-api' and 'react-front'. In the node-api, package.json file, I have the line "heroku-postbuild": "cd ../react-front && npm install && npm run build"
which is giving this error. How do I fix this?

Comment: Try `"cd ./react-front` instead of `"cd ../react-front` You don't want to go a folder structure up if the current folder contains a folder named `react-font`.

Comment: But the package.json is in node-api folder So wont I have to go up one step and then into react-front. On the terminal it works fine

Comment: I just tried 'cd ./react-front' but it still gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

try it: `npm run deploy:full`

```
    "scripts": {
        "build:ui": "cd ../react-front && npm install && npm run build",
        "deploy": "git push heroku master",
        "deploy:full": "npm run build:ui && git add . && git commit -m uibuild && npm run deploy"
    }
```

**Dont't** change heroku default `build` command